# Shift of Chain Complex as iterated Mapping Cone

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

This question is about exercise 3.8 of the book/notes on Higher Algebra by Aron Mazel-Gee (https://etale.site/teaching/w21/math-128-lecture-notes.pdf#page20). To proof is that there is a canonical homotopy equivalence $\Sigma M \simeq \text{hcoker}(N \to \text{hcoker}(f))$, where $f\colon M \to N$ is a chain map between chain complexes and $\Sigma$ denotes the shift by one degree (equivalently $\Sigma M \simeq \text{hcoker}(M \to 0)$ as defined on the same page (modulo signs). Moreover the homotopy cokernel of a chain map is also known as the mapping cone $\text{cone}(f)$.

I can check the homotopy equivalence by hand (part (a) of exercise 3.8) but I want to use the universal property, that is solving part (b). Just putting in the definitions, one sees that $\text{Ch}_R(\text{hcoker}(N \to \text{hcoker}(f)), T)$ corresponds to

- a map $g\colon N \to T$
- a nullhomotopy of $gf\colon M \to N \to T$ and
- a nullhomotopy of $g\colon N \to T$.

On the other hand, $\text{Ch}_R(\Sigma M, T)$ corresponds to just a nullhomotopy of the zero map $0\colon M \to T$. Now these should be related up to homotopy in order to obtain the result. Any hints? Thanks in advance!